# Profling a python process when there are multiple processes running on the system

Tags: python, profiling, python-2.x, cpu-usage

`time.clock()` measures cpu time. Let's say there are multiple processes running on the system then in that case its possible our python process might be swapped out at various time during execution by scheduler. So there will be a period when our python process will be in waiting state. 
In that case can we still measure cpu ticks just for our process-ignoring everything else thats scheduled to be run on the system? 
Basically the results should not change depending on what else is running on the cpu. the numbers should be same as there was single core and our process was the only process bound to that core. I want to profile from within the code.

Comment: As for any other measurement or benchmark make sure your system is as free of interference as possible to get useful results.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes. Thats what I am used to from HFT world but right now need to profile some python service which I cant run in isolation. Actual problem is more complicated as the service runs greenlet (gevent) and I need to profile individual greenlets in that process. New to python world so getting my head around.

Comment: A greenlet is not like a thread since it delivers only pseudo-concurrently. They are not easy to profile but that might be possible with GreenletProfiler or yappi according to [this source](https://emptysqua.re/blog/greenletprofiler/).

Comment: For processes, there's [psutil.Process().cpu_times()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_times).